# Opencv nonfree package installation in raspberry pi 2 mod b

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

Is it possible to install opencv nonfree package in raspberry pi 2 mod b.?
As i have done coding in C++ and when i ported my code to raspberry pi(arm processor) with raspbian OS this code was not working as it was showing unable to locate nonfree packge. tried with adding repositories

```
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:xqms/opencv-nonfree

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install libopencv-nonfree-dev
```

and many other ways still it was not working. then i changed the raspbian OS to ubuntu 14.04 LTS raspberry pi supported, still no change..
Is it that raspberry pi with arm processor won't support this package?

Please help me by suggesting the method how to install this package.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Looks like](https://launchpad.net/~xqms/+archive/ubuntu/opencv-nonfree/+packages) it's only been built for i386 and amd64, no pre-built arm packages there... You probably have to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But how we build it ourself in the component?